# How does the Windows shortcut know about renaming the file to which it refers?

Tags: windows, api, winapi, shortcut

How does the Windows shortcut know about renaming the file to which it refers? How to intercept the message when the file was renamed? Is there a corresponding function Win32 API for this?

Comment: I don't think it does know about the renaming. What evidence do you have for this?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.10.windowsconfidential.aspx

Comment: @CodyGray - well I never knew that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortcut causes the target file's NTFS attributes to be updated with an ObjectID, this is the value that the shortcut actually "points" to.

Resolving them on-demand is done by the *distributed link tracking service*.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363997(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

To detect file name changes and the like you can use  FindFirstChangeNotification. I've not worked with shortcuts